# Refresh datatable column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

How can I refresh the datatable after loading a dynamic content from an Ajax request? The flow is this, 
1. a button will be click and this button contains an ID
2. I'll use this ID to do an Ajax request to the server
3. The server will reply the record from the passed ID
4. I'll load clear the initialized datatable and load the new content from the Ajax
5. Show bootstrap modal.

Now my problem is the header column and the content row of the datatable does not fit as shown below
[image]

The weird thing about this is when I resize my browser the header column fits with the table content.

Below is my code for this

```
<table id="mytable" class="cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead class="table-header">
     <tr>                            
       <th>Comptetitor Item ID</th>
       <th>Competitor Seller</th>
       <th>Competitor Title</th>
       <th>Competitor Price</th>
       <th>Competitor Quantity Sold</th>
       <th>Competitor Listing Status</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
</table>


table1 = $('#mytable').DataTable({
        scrollY         : "250px",
        scrollCollapse  : true,
        fixedColumns    : false,
        paging          : false,
        searching       : false,
        bInfo           : false,
        bSort           : false,
    });

$(document).on("click", ".a_tag_link",function() {
        var row_id = $(this).data("row_id");   

        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/ajax/server_process',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                view_id: $(this).data("row_id")
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $.blockUI({ baseZ: 9999 });
            },
            success:function(response){                                   
                table1.rows().remove().draw();                   

                $("#mymodal").modal("show");
                table1.rows.add(response.data).draw(true);
            },
            complete: function(){
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Kindly help me with this. I just want the column header content to fit the table content without the browser being resized.

Updates: The table is fixed when I remove the scrollY attribute. But the problem is that the content is very large and I need the table to have a fix height

Comment: Please share your HTML markup for the table

Comment: @Norsk question updated and added the html markup for the table

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. Are you adding any styles to those classnames that might be doing it? Such as different widths or anything

Comment: No I'm not modifying any styling. When I click the A tag it opens a bootstrap modal but the table header in the modal does not resize and I have to resize my browser for the header to fit the table column content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting for the modal to fully load, and then append the data. Probably, the datatable holder is not visible yet, and did not get its final dimensions:

```
success:function(response){                                   
    table1.rows().remove().draw();                   
    $("#mymodal").modal("show");
    setTimeout(function() {
        table1.rows.add(response.data).draw(true);
    },250);        
},
```

You could also listen to modal's custom events, and draw the datatable when the modal has finished its animation:

```
success:function(response){                                   
    table1.rows().remove().draw();                   
    $("#mymodal").modal("show");        
    table1.rows.add(response.data);             
},

...

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#mytable').DataTable().draw(true);
})
```

Comment: wow thanks. That really solves it... Great answer you really saved me